# How to avoid "Terminating app due to uncaught exception"

Tags: ios, objective-c, error-handling, exception, migration

There are times when you face exception and crash the app. In my case, here:

```
+ (void)saveContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context
{
    if ([context hasChanges]) {
        [context performBlockAndWait:^{
            NSError *error = nil;
            BOOL saved = [context save:&error];
            if (!saved) {
                // do some real error handling
                NSLog(@"Could not save master context due to %@", error);
            }
            else {
                if ([context parentContext]) {
                    [self saveContext:[context parentContext]];
                }
            }
        }];
    }
}
```

It terminated due to save context while migrating Coredata. I don't understand why that piece of code doesn't escape the exception. Shouldn't it log "Could not save master context due to $error"?

Question is, is the NSError has any meaning? How to escape the exception and crash? Should I use @try-catch instead of NSError?

**EDIT 1**

So, thanks to Mr. TheEye below, I understand that NSError doesn't escape this `uncaught exception`, and to avoid the crash, I better use @try-catch instead.

But, "it would be better to correct the cause of the exception, as it should not happen.", so I thought it should be better to update the question as below:

How should I make the context wait until migration done and perform save? In the case of migration failed, I will remove all context and persistent store, so the save process (in case migration failed) should be nullified. Else (migration successful), save normally.

**Edit 2**

So, to "correct the cause of the exception", I ended up fixed save context like this:

```
if (context.hasChanges && context.persistentStoreCoordinator.persistentStores.count) {
...
}
```

And that concluded my issue. Thanks for spending your time here.

Comment: If you get an exception while saving after your migration, the migration failed and probably will fail again when you try again. If it's reproducible, reproduce the problem and take note of the exception, then post the exception in your question to get help in solving it.

Comment: I get the exception while saving during the migration process. It say: Illegal attempt to save to a file that was never opened.  "This NSPersistentStoreCoordinator has no persistent stores (schema mismatch or migration failure).  It cannot perform a save operation."

Comment: Well, then you have your reason - the persistent store for the context was not opened yet. There are quite a lot of questions for that error on stack overflow, have a look at them (eg https://www.google.com/search?q=This+NSPersistentStoreCoordinator+has+no+persistent+stores+%28schema+mismatch+or+migration&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error object only is for expected errors - if something unforeseen happens (eg some threading issue), an exception will be thrown. You can catch it with a try/catch, but it would be better to correct the cause of the exception, as it should not happen.

Comment: But, does the NSError there in my code has any meaning? Have you ever seen it work?

Comment: Of course - can't remember one for saving a database context, but for network connections I get them all the time ;-).

Comment: That said, for a lot of calls the exact error value can be ignored (after printing for debug purposes), quite often nothing can be done anyway once it happens, except notifying the user of a problem and trying again later.

Comment: Yeah, I also saw a lot in network connection. It's as exactly as you say. Also, you said it would be better if I correct the cause of the exception, so can you suggest for my case? How should I make it `saveContext` *AFTER* the migration process has been done?

Comment: Well, to fix an exception I have to know what the exception was.

Comment: Please check my edited question. I'm updating right away.